# Code after DispatchGroup().wait() never called

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to make my call to the service synchronous because I want my call to return my object already mapped with generics.

Here is the code:

```
func execute<T: Mappable>(request: HttpRequest, responseType: T.Type) throws -> T? {
    var responseObject: T?
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()

    Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request(request.stringURL, method: request.method, parameters: request.parameter.toJSON(), encoding: request.encoding, headers: request.headers)
        .validate()
        .response(completionHandler: { response in
            responseObject = self.singleResult(dataResult: response.data, resultType: T.self)
            group.leave()
    })

    group.wait()

    guard let response = responseObject else {
        return nil
    }

    return response
}
```

The problem is that the code under group.wait() is never called but with Charles I can see that the request is working and have ended.

Comment: Use completion handler. You can not use `DispatchGroup` in this way.

Comment: Have you tried using DispatchQueue's notify(queue:work:)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) to give you more control on handling asynchronous code. Using `PromiseKit`, you will be able to access the object in the same way you are trying above.

If you don't want to add dependency then you can use the `completion handler` as below to get the object when request is ended.

```
func execute<T: Mappable>(request: HttpRequest, responseType: T.Type, completion: @escaping ((T?) -> Void)) {
        Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request(request.stringURL, method: request.method, parameters: request.parameter.toJSON(), encoding: request.encoding, headers: request.headers)
            .validate()
            .response(completionHandler: { response in
                let mappedObject: T? = self.singleResult(dataResult: response.data, resultType: T.self)
                completion(mappedObject)
            })
}
```

Then you can call the method as below,

```
let service = YourService()
service.execute(request: fetchUser, responseType: User.self) { user in
            guard let user = user else { return }
            print(user.name)
        }
```