# Queue with alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have a problem with the execution of the tasks when i use Alamofire
I use two time Alamofire, a first to collect a data (token) that I will then use it to send my Post request.

The problem between my two requests, the recovery of the data is done after the second request.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class Helper {
    func alomofireGet(URL: String) -> JSON {
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.test.com", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)
        var contenuJSON = JSON()
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get).responseJSON(queue: queue) { (reponse) in
            if reponse.result.isSuccess {
                contenuJSON = JSON(reponse.result.value!)
                print(contenuJSON)
            }
            else {
                contenuJSON = JSON(reponse.result.error!)
            }
        }
        return contenuJSON
    }
    func alomofirePost(URL: String, Paramaters: Dictionary<String, Any>) -> JSON {
        var contenuJSON = JSON()
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: Paramaters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (reponse) in
            if reponse.result.isSuccess {
                contenuJSON = JSON(reponse.result.value!)
            }
            else {
                contenuJSON = JSON(reponse.result.error!)
            }
        }
        return contenuJSON
    }
}
```

In the new file = DIFFERENCE WITH CONTENT TOKEN

```
let request = Helper()
@IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordText: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
}
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    let contenuJSON = request.alomofireGet(URL: "http://192.168.1.7/app_dev.php/login/app")
    print(contenuJSON)
    let token = contenuJSON["csrfToken"].stringValue
    print(token) // /\ EMPTY
    let Paramaters = ["_csrf_token": token, "_password": self.passwordText.text!, "_redirect_url": "", "t_path": "", "_username": self.emailText.text!]
    let contenuRequest = request.alomofirePost(URL: "http://192.168.1.7/app_dev.php/login_check", Paramaters: Paramaters)
    print(token) // /\ FULL /\
}
```

}

Comment: You are missing the concept of asynchrone. `return contenuJSON` will be called BEFORE `contenuJSON = JSON(...)` (you can add prints, you'll see). Look for "Swift + Closure + Async"

Comment: You need to use `completion` block. You can apply from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API call to Alamofire are the async process, hence your `alamofireGet` and `alamofirePost` returning just initialized json object - `JSON()` which does not have any data.

**Solution:**

You should use `@escaping closure`, which will hold the control until you get the result from first API call.

```
func alomofireGet(URL: String, onCompletion:((JSON) -> Void)) {
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.test.com", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent)
    var contentJSON = JSON()
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get).responseJSON(queue: queue) { (reponse) in
        // Load contentJSON with data
        if reponse.result.isSuccess {
            contenuJSON = JSON(reponse.result.value!)
        } else {
            contenuJSON = JSON(reponse.result.error!)
        }
        // Send contentJSON via `onCompletion` block
        onCompletion(contenuJSON)
    }
}

func alomofirePost(URL: String, Paramaters: Dictionary<String, Any>, onCompletion: @escaping ((_ response: JSON) -> Void)) {
    var contenuJSON = JSON()
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .post, parameters: Paramaters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (reponse) in
        // Load contentJSON with data
        if reponse.result.isSuccess {
            contenuJSON = JSON(reponse.result.value!)
        } else {
            contenuJSON = JSON(reponse.result.error!)
        }
        // Send contentJSON via `onCompletion` block
        onCompletion(contenuJSON)
    }
}
```

Call it in your view-controller as:

```
    let usernameStr = self.emailText.text!
    let passwordStr = self.passwordText.text! 

    Helper().alomofireGet(URL: "http://192.168.1.7/app_dev.php/login/app") { contenuJSON in
        print(contenuJSON)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let token = contenuJSON["csrfToken"].stringValue
            print(token)

            let Paramaters = ["_csrf_token": token, "_password": passwordStr, "_redirect_url": "", "t_path": "", "_username": usernameStr]
            Helper().alomofirePost(URL: "http://192.168.1.7/app_dev.php/login_check", Paramaters: Paramaters) { contenuJSON in
                print(token)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I try this but I have a new error message = " UITextField.text must be used from main thread only' I'v try with DispatchQueue.main.async but don't work. May be a bad use

Comment: Try taking it in another variable or can use weak reference of text-fields. Updated my answer.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal Please can I ask one question related to `Alamofire synchronous`?